# How can I detect if my service is using SSL or TLS and which version

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, weblogic, tls1.2

There are options to specify TLS or SSL on weblogic server & webservers  communicating [LISTENING] over HTTPS.

I do not have access to web or app server configurations, however i wish to determine if my connection to webserver [nginx, apache http webserver] or appserver [weblogic] over HTTPS is using SSL or TLS and which version of it.

If & how is it possible to determine ? Kindly suggest.

Comment: You could try pointing [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) at it.

Comment: OpenSSL is commonly used, https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-testing-with-openssl.html

Comment: Make a network capture with wireshark between apache and WebLogic and inspect traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to use some online tools for your service or your service is not hosted to public internet, then there are somethings that you can try.

You can use [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html) as `nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p <port> <host>` to see what TLS versions and particularly what ciphers on which your server is responding.

If you don't have nmap or you are not allowed to install nmap on the system from your the service is reachable, then you can use some default tools to see what ciphers are available.
eg:

- `openssl`: You can use openssl to connect to the server and you can specify the ssl ciphers in the command line.
  eg:

  `$ openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> -tls1_2 -cipher AES128-GCM-SHA256`

If you see a successful connection, then you can be sure that the server is able to negotiate using that TLS version, `TLSv1.2` in the example, and using that cipher, `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` in the example.

You can find all the ciphers that are valid for openssl [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/c4de074e6385a86a43a30fee574e77f9dcabb022/doc/man1/ciphers.pod). A sample run would look like this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1_2 -cipher AES128-GCM-SHA256
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Los Angeles, O = Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers, OU = Technology, CN = www.example.org
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
....
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHQDCCBiigAwIBAgIQD9B43Ujxor1NDyupa2A4/jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBN
...
0Gs4+eH6F9h3SojmPTYkT+8KuZ9w84Mn+M8qBXUQoYoKgIjN
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Los Angeles/O=Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers/OU=Technology/CN=www.example.org
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4297 bytes and written 408 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    ...
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 57 04 cc 0f 69 dc 93 6c-e5 d6 50 0a 1c d0 d8 ce   W...i..l..P.....
    ...
    0090 - 9a 34 af 1e c2 09 cf 00-6d 68 36 41 09 40 de 0a   .4......mh6A.@..

    Start Time: 1558594372
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

- `curl`: you can use curl to do the same thing. eg:

```
$ curl https://example.com --tlsv1.2 --ciphers AES128-GCM-SHA256 -w "%{http_code}\n" -o /dev/null -s
```

In this case, you will get the output as a valid response code, say `200` if the connection is successful and `000` is the Handshake failed, so you can differentiate using that.

Note: the TLS version supported in `openssl` and `curl` can be looked up by checking the `--help` in both cases. eg:

curl:

```
 -1, --tlsv1         Use >= TLSv1 (SSL)
     --tlsv1.0       Use TLSv1.0 (SSL)
     --tlsv1.1       Use TLSv1.1 (SSL)
     --tlsv1.2       Use TLSv1.2 (SSL)
     --tlsv1.3       Use TLSv1.3 (SSL)
```

openssl:

```
-tls1_2       - just use TLSv1.2
-tls1_1       - just use TLSv1.1
-tls1         - just use TLSv1
-dtls1        - just use DTLSv1
```